# Implementation of Excess-Mass or Mass-Volume curves

Tags: algorithm, implementation, unsupervised-learning, anomaly-detection

I am looking for an implementation of [Excess-Mass or Mass-Volume curves](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.01152.pdf) which are used for the evaluation of unsupervised anomaly detection algorithms.

I'd prefer an implementation in Python but I could re-write it from any other language.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This lacks documentation, but if you've read the papers you can infer what all the functions do. Unfortunately, there is no LICENSE, so you will need permission from the Author
https://github.com/ngoix/EMMV_benchmarks

Comment: Thanks a lot @hoj201!